# JQuery Mobile ui-datepicker go to specific month onload

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

How can I go to a specific month when the document loads please?

Here is the link to it:

http://jquerymobile.com/test/experiments/ui-datepicker/

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this (not tested)

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  var queryDate = new Date(2011,5,1,0,0,0); // 1st of June 2011
  $('#date').datepicker({defaultDate: queryDate});
});
```

Comment: Duplicate question?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5923688/jquery-mobile-ui-datepicker-setting-a-specific-default-date

Comment: Yes, I can see the JSFiddle works but my project uses jquery.ui.datepicker.mobile.js too and I think that this could be the problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926508/datepicker-datepickergetdate-getmonth-is-not-a-function