# JQuery-Mobile UI DatePicker Setting a specific default date

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am having problems trying to set the default date on JQuery Mobile's UI datepicker.

Can someone please help?

Here is the full source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"> 
    <title>jQuery Mobile Framework - Datepicker</title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4.1/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4.1/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="jquery.ui.datepicker.mobile.css" /> 

    <script>
        //reset type=date inputs to text
        $( document ).bind( "mobileinit", function(){
            $.mobile.page.prototype.options.degradeInputs.date = true;
        }); 
    </script>

    <script src="jQuery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.ui.datepicker.mobile.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
var queryDate = new Date();
queryDate.setFullYear(2009,11,01);
$('#date').datepicker({defaultDate: queryDate});


   });
  </script>

</head> 
<body> 

<div data-role="page">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>jQuery UI's Datepicker Styled for mobile</h1>       
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <p>The included files extend the jQuery UI datepicker to make it suitable for touch devices. This plugin is not included in jQuery Mobile by default, so you'll need to include the files yourself if you'd like to use them. Scroll down for usage instructions.</p>

        <form action="#" method="get">
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="date">Date Input:</label>
                <input type="date" name="date" id="date" value=""  />
            </div>      
        </form>


        <h2>Usage Instructions</h2>

        <p>The datepicker auto-generates from a regular <code>input</code> element with a <code>type="date"</code> attribute.</p>

        <pre><code>
&lt;label for=&quot;date&quot;&gt;Date Input:&lt;/label&gt;
&lt;input type=&quot;date&quot; name=&quot;date&quot; id=&quot;date&quot; value=&quot;&quot;  /&gt;     
        </code></pre>

        <p>We'd recommend wrapping the label and input in a fieldcontain div for presentation purposes, and these elements should be placed within a <code>form</code> element for C-Grade browser accessibility.</p>

        <p><strong>Note:</strong> This plugin is not included in jQuery Mobile by default, so you'll need to include the following files in order to use it:</p>

<pre><code>
  &lt;link rel=&quot;stylesheet&quot; href=&quot;jquery.ui.datepicker.mobile.css&quot; /&gt; 
  &lt;script src=&quot;jQuery.ui.datepicker.js&quot;&gt;&lt;/script&gt;
  &lt;script src=&quot;jquery.ui.datepicker.mobile.js&quot;&gt;&lt;/script&gt;
</code></pre>

        <p>You'll also want to configure the page plugin to convert "date" input elements to "text" inputs after they're enhanced with our datepicker, so that no native datepicker will conflict with the custom one we're adding. To do this, bind to the "mobileinit" event and set input types of "date" back to text using the page plugin's options:</p>
<pre><code> 
&lt;script&gt;
  //reset type=date inputs to text
  $( document ).bind( &quot;mobileinit&quot;, function(){
    $.mobile.page.prototype.options.degradeInputs.date = true;
  });   
&lt;/script&gt; 
</code></pre>

<p>Be sure to place this event binding in a script that loads after jQuery, but before jQuery Mobile. Check this page's source for an example.</p>





    </div>

</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  var queryDate = new Date(2009,11,01);
  $('#date').datepicker({defaultDate: queryDate});
});
```

And that's it.

Hope this helps Cheers

Comment: I've tried it and it doesn't change anything. It's driving me crazy :o/

Comment: Which version of JQM is this for?, im using 1.4.5 and i get this error:                          "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function", my setter code is     $('#fechaHastaRegEntrada').datepicker({defaultDate: today});    and the definition is    <input type="date" data-clear-btn="true" name="fechaHastaRegEntrada" id="fechaHastaRegEntrada" value="">

Comment: I'm also on jQ 11.1.2 and jQM 1.4.5 and it does not work for me. I can't stop wonder how jQ team made so wicked control, like Date isn't so necessary information!? Funny :/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set both the calendar date and the input text date this is the only solution that I found:

```
$.datepicker.formatDate('dd/mm/yyyy'); // my data format
var d = new Date(); // today or other date
var curr_date = ("0" + (d.getDate())).slice(-2); // two digits day
var curr_month =("0" + (d.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2); // two digits month
var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
$('#myDatePickerControl').datepicker({defaultDate: d}); // set input text
$('#myDatePickerControl').val(curr_date+'/'+curr_month+'/'+curr_year); // set calendar control
```